# Roland Jupiter 80 undo changes to registration/live set/tone

Tags: synthesizer

If I make changes to a registration X on my Roland Jupiter 80 synthesizer, for instance by changing the upper live set, how do I go back to the saved version of the registration?

As it is now, the registration is marked as edited when I leave the registration screen and I come back to it again. Can this be done with the Utility (cogwheels icon)? Or is there a keyboard shortcut for this?
The paper manual index doesn't have an entry for "Discard" or "Undo".

Comment: Try searching the manual for "reset" or "cancel".

Comment: Thanks, good suggestions. Unfortunately "cancel" turned up "cancelling save of registration/tone" and "reset" only yielded "Factory Reset".

Next thing to try is copy registration and set source and destination to be the same, that could remove my changes.